# Count subsequences

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

Given an array of **integers** we need to count its subsequences following given condition:

- let's **i1, i2, i3...iN** are the indexes of the given array and **Ai1, Ai2, Ai3....AiN** are the corresponding elements. **X** is an integer; **N** length of the array; **A** is the array;
- Count all the subsequence having **(Ai1^Ai2^Ai3^...^AiN)&X == 0**;

```
    // A = [5,3,7], N = 3, X = 1
    // Now there are 2 pow 3 subsequences are there
    // consider empty array is also a subsequence
    public long count(int[] A, int N, int X){

    }
```

Comment: What approach have you tried ?

Comment: I tried standard solution for count subsequence but how to store the previous result? This not as simple as string or no comparison. Where we do dp[i] = 2*dp[i-1] and after that check from the map and subtract the same occurrences.

Comment: What's the maximum value of X and N?

Comment: for X take any value grater than or equal to 1 and I forgot about N but take 10^5